# How do I store an input value in an array using foreach?

Tags: c#

This might be an easy one, but as a beginner I'm currently stuck. I tried the **tempArray[i] = inputTemp;** but it didn't seem to store the value properly when printing the list. Any ideas?

```
        foreach (int i in tempArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");
            double inputTemp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            tempArray[i] = inputTemp;
        }
        // Print out the array
        foreach (double i in tempArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not working is because `foreach` loops through the values in `tempArray`. Therefore `i` is not an index but actually a value of `tempArray`, which is probably 0 in each iteration because the array hasn't been initialized with values yet.

You want to use `for` instead to make `i` the array index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");
    double inputTemp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    tempArray[i] = inputTemp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `for` statement in this case

```
for (var index = 0; index < tempArray.Length; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");
    double inputTemp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    tempArray[i] = inputTemp;
}
```

`Foreach` statement only serves for iterating over an `IEnumerable`. It abstracts from the fact that the values are stored in an array and you can't modify the underlying array from it.

*Technically, you could do the following, but it goes against the design of the language and I would never recommend it. Notice that the iteration variable `item` is not used*

```
// Don't use
foreach (var (index, item) in tempArray.Select((x, i) => (i, x)))
{
    tempArray[index] = whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Marlon . If you want a fix with less changes (although his method is better): You can just initialize an index variable, and then use the foreach loop (which iterates through values in the array as opposed to indices)

```
    //this index variable can track the index being changed
    int index = 0;
    foreach (int i in tempArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");
        double inputTemp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        tempArray[index] = inputTemp;
        index++;
    }
    // Print out the array
    foreach (double i in tempArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies! Since I'm learning I wanted to compare the for and foreach loops  to see if I could achieve the same result. And thought I've missed something in my foreach when tested it. However, from your answers I understand foreach wasn't optimal in this case.